# Rails 3 ActiveRecord temporary tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, temp-tables

How do I do the following in Rails 3?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE average_user_total_time 
  (SELECT SUM(time) AS time_taken 
        FROM scores 
        WHERE created_at >= '2010-10-10' 
                and created_at <= '2010-11-11' 
        GROUP BY user_id);

SELECT COUNT(*) from average_user_total_time WHERE time_taken > 60 and time_taken < 600
```

I have tried to do something like

```
create_table (:average_user_total_time), :temporary=> true do |t|

end
```

but not sure how to use it exactly. I need to use it within my app and not in a migration.

Comment: Perhaps you should just use raw SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Andrew, I ended up using the following advice.

http://richtextblog.blogspot.com/2007/09/mysql-temporary-tables-and-rails.html